# php word check if they are the same

Tags: php, html, arrays

I need that they check my word witch i written in text field. If 2 words the same i should get message - "They are the same".

```
<?php
function array_random($arr, $num = 1) {
    shuffle($arr);

    $r = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
        $r[] = $arr[$i];
    }
    return $num == 1 ? $r[0] : $r;
}

$a = array("snow", "ball", "side");
//print_r(array_random($a));
//print_r(array_random($a, 3));

?>
<form name='form' method='post' align = "center">
<?php 
$zod = (array_random($a)); echo $zod; ?> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" ><?php
if((isset($_POST['name'])) && !empty($_POST['name']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo '&nbsp;'.$name;
}
?><br/><br>

<input name="select" type="submit" onclick="select()" value="select" /> 

</form>
```

Comment: I need, gimme codez now. Hur Hur

Comment: Uhh... why don't you get use; if ( $_POST['field1'] == $_POST['field2'] ) { // true }

Comment: @Tosfera because there's only 1 input on the form

Comment: Well, then simply use the $_POST and $zod to compare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple comparison uses the '==' operator. These can be used to compare something. You want to compare a posted value with the one from your array. which is random:

```
<?php
    function array_random($arr, $num = 1) {
        shuffle($arr);

        $r = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
            $r[] = $arr[$i];
        }
        return $num == 1 ? $r[0] : $r;
    }

    if ( isset ( $_POST['submit'] ) && isset ( $_POST['name'] ) ) {
        if ( $_POST['compare'] == $_POST['name'] )
            echo "They are the same, hurray!<br />";
        else
            echo "These don't match!";
    }

    $a = array ( "snow", "ball", "side" );
    $rand = array_random ( $a );
?>
<form name='form' method='post' align = "center">
    Please type the word: <?php echo $rand; ?>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" >
    <input type="hidden" name="compare" id="compare" value="<?php echo $rand ?>" >
    <input name="submit" type="submit" onclick="select()" value="select" /> 
</form>
```

As you wanted, a random value is picked and compared to what the user posted.

Comment: No problem, enjoy the upcoming days. :)